# Netconsole error, eth0 doesn't support polling

Tags: kernel

I am configuring netconsole on ubuntu 11.10, but when i tried to load the module using modprobe, i got the following error:

```
netconsole: etho doesn't support polling, aborting
netconsole: cleaning up
```

Anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Either the network device, or the driver that manages it, is not capable of providing polling support. Make sure your kernel is configured with CONFIG_NET_POLL_CONTROLLER enabled. If this is the case, then likely you'll need to use a different network device.